# How can I make a multiline title work in a textbox?

Tags: titles, tcolorbox, text

I have this code

```
    \title{
\tcbhighmath[frame style={left color=Green!70!black,right color=Red!95!black},interior style={left color=Green!35!white,right color=Red!50!white},boxrule=2pt]{
\text{
\Large Here is a failing example of a long multiline title \\ that I made in latex
}
}}
```

which produces a single line title, when I want a linebreak where \ is. I've tried unsuccessfully to use an array to fix it, so I was wondering if anyone could help.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? https://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/academic-presentation-template/jpgfpsstrwzd I'm just using this template in overleaf. I'm having issues with inserting images on it aswell :/

Comment: `\tcbhighmath` only works with one line contents. Unless you combine it with `empheq`. Look at page 377 and 388 in tcolorbox documentation. I suggest to change to a regular `tcolorbox` with a fixed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `\tcbhighmath` is used for producing frame, you should construct multi-lined expression, e.g., using `array` environment.

```
\title{
\tcbhighmath[frame style={left color=Green!70!black,
    right color=Red!95!black},
    interior style={left color=Green!35!white,right color=Red!50!white},
    boxrule=2pt]{
    \Large\begin{array}{c}
        \text{Academic Presentation} \\
        \text{template}
    \end{array}
}}
```

[image]